# How to make text on one line?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I currently have text which looks like this. I want the 1600+ happy eaters to be all in one line. The title is fine as it is. I am currently using flexbox if this helps.

[image]

```css
.currentcitiesmaincontent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="currentcitiesmaincontent">
  <div>
    Lisbon<br>
    <p> 1600+ happy eaters</p>
  </div>
  <div>SAN Franscisco</div>
  <div>Berlin</div>
  <div>London</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `flex` layout on inline divs too to make it on one line.

```css
.currentcitiesmaincontent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.currentcitiesmaincontent div {
  display: flex;
}

.currentcitiesmaincontent p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="currentcitiesmaincontent">
  <div>
    Lisbon<br>
    <p> 1600+ happy eaters</p>
  </div>
  <div>SAN Franscisco</div>
  <div>Berlin</div>
  <div>London</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should create a class for the paragraph you want with `white-space: nowrap;`.

```css
p.nowrap {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<p class="nowrap"> 1600+ happy eaters</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

i think this is what you are searching for

```css
.currentcitiesmaincontent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.currentcitiesmaincontent > div:first-child{
display : flex;
}

* {
margin : 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="currentcitiesmaincontent">
  <div>
    Lisbon<br>
    <p> 1600+ happy eaters</p>
  </div>
  <div>SAN Franscisco</div>
  <div>Berlin</div>
  <div>London</div>
</div>
```